# Ошибка в тесте Jest при использовании "testing-library"

Tags: javascript, reactjs, юнит-тесты, jest

Написал тест для компоненты React, в которой используется setTimeout, но он не работает, как я ожидал. **Мок-функция consoleLog не вызывается**. Где я допустил ошибку, подскажите, пожалуйста.

**Код компоненты:**

```
import React, { useEffect } from "react";

const Component = () => {
  const initialization = () => {
    setTimeout(() => {
      console.log("Test");
    }, 3000);
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    initialization();
  }, []);

  return <h1>Test</h1>;
};

export default Component;
```

**Код теста:**

```
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import Component from "./Component";

jest.useFakeTimers();

it("Correct call console.log", () => {
  const consoleLog = jest.fn();
  console.log = consoleLog;

  render(<Component />);
  jest.runAllTimers();

  expect(consoleLog).toHaveBeenCalledWith("Test");
});
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Что значит «не работает как ожидал»?

Comment: @AlexeyTen Тест валится, но должен работать.

Answer (score 0):

Я нашел решение проблемы. Я просто перенес строчку `jest.useFakeTimers();` внутрь самого теста. Теперь тест работает корректно.

**Код рабочего теста для этого компонента:**

```
import { render } from "@testing-library/react";
import Component from "./Component";

it("Correct call console.log", () => {
  jest.useFakeTimers();
  const consoleLog = jest.fn();
  console.log = consoleLog;

  render(<Component />);
  jest.runAllTimers();

  expect(consoleLog).toHaveBeenCalledWith("Test");
});
```